# how to use NOT operator for integers in JAVA

Tags: java, operators, logical-operators

how to use NOT operator for integers in JAVA  [image]

when i put NOT operator (!) it shows an error 
package com.learnJava.first;

```
public class LogicalOpTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int p,q;

        System.out.println("P\t Q\t AND\t OR\t XOR\t NOT\n");

        p = 1;
        q = 1;

        System.out.println(p+ "\t " + q + "\t " + (p&q) + "\t " + (p|q) + "\t " + (p^q) + "\t " + !p );

        p = 1;
        q = 0;

        System.out.println(p + "\t " + q + "\t " + (p&q) + "\t " + (p|q) + "\t " + (p^q) + "\t " + !p);

        p = 0;
        q = 1;

        System.out.println(p + "\t " + q + "\t " + (p&q) + "\t " + (p|q) + "\t " + (p^q) + "\t " + !p);

        p = 0;
        q = 0;

        System.out.println(p + "\t " + q + "\t " + (p&q) + "\t " + (p|q) + "\t " + (p^q) + "\t " + !p);


    }

}
```

Comment: The operators are explained in the JLS and the Tutorial. Read the Fine Manual.

Answer (score 6):

You would need to use [the bitwise complement operator, `~`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.5), not [the logical complement operator, `!`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.6).

---

However, you seem to have a bit of a mismatch in your code: your class is called `LogicalOpTable`, but you are otherwise using *bitwise* operators, not logical operators.

If you really want to do logical operations, using `boolean` values instead of `int`s.

If you really want to do bitwise operations, name your class so it's not as confusing ;)

Comment: I'm new to JAVA that's why confusing.. then how to use NOT for int?

Comment: There is no such thing as "not" for `int`. What is "not 123"?

Answer (score 1):

one year later, but hey, maybe it's still relevant.

I had the same issue with this exercise, but I went a different way. If I'm not mistaken, p and q were initially of the boolean type and the task was to modify the table to show 1s and 0s instead of true and false.

What I did was convert each expression as a whole from boolean to int (e.g. int a = (!p) ? 1 : 0;) and replace them with the variable for the rest of the code (e.g System.out.println(..... + a); )